# OpenGL 3.1 GLFW on a linux intel machine

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, intel

I'm trying to initialize a glfw window with a minimum version of 3.1 or 3.0 but neither parameter will create a window (both return false on glfwOpenWindow).

In theory my system should support 3.1 (Intel hd4000) and I've definitely gotten it working in the past but I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 recently and can't find the code that worked.

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?

```
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    return -1;
}

glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )//error if not created
//...
```

Comment: Try knockin' off that `GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES` hint.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.  Thanks though!

Comment: And `glxinfo`'s `OpenGL version string` is >= `3.1`?

Comment: Err...  Its 3.0.  According to the internet Intel HD4000 should support 3.1 on linux.  Either way I changed VERSION_MINOR to 0 and still had the same result

Comment: @pdel: you must install the latest (at the current date) versions of MesaGL, Kernel DRM modules, latest DRI2 libs and latest X.Org to get 3.1 support with Intel HD.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've done the usual apt-get update/upgrade ritual so my packages are up to date with the repos.  Obviously Ubuntu likes to lag a bit behind the bleeding edge but not by a huge amount.  I can get 2.1 to work fine so I assume this means that the requisite libraries are there.  Whats the best way to confirm that they're actually globally up to date?

Comment: @pdel: modern versions of `glxinfo` will report _two_ different versions: the "OpenGL version string" (which will be <= 3.0 for all mesa-based GL implementations, and the "OpenGL core profile version string", which nowadays can be up to 3.3.